# How to configure SystemJS to be aware of an already loaded library like jquery?

Tags: javascript, systemjs, jspm, adminlte

I'm working on an admin panel built on top of [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview) template. The template depends on jquery, bootstrap and some other custom plugins that must be previously included using script tags in document head.

I'm using Jspm to manage libraries, some libraries like `Toastr` will require jQuery as a dependency, and will install and load another copy of jQuery.

I'm trying to figure out how to configure SystemJS in order to:
a) Tell SystemJS that I don't need install another copy of jQuery and
b) avoid duplicate loading of jQuery, since it's a global dependency that was previously loaded. How to achieve this?

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
...
<script src="system.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        "map": { 
            "jquery": window.jQuery //???
        }
});
</script>
<script>
    System.import('main').
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to use [System.set](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/system-api.md#systemjssetmodulename-module)

```
System.set( 'jQuery', System.newModule({'default': window.jQuery }) );
```

This assumes the global is expected to be the 'default'. You can also specify other exports as well by passing in more key / values to [System.newModule](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/system-api.md#systemjsnewmoduleobject---module).

If you can, it would be better to import your globals like other scripts because globals can have dependencies and systemjs can manage the load order for you through [meta config setup](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#meta)

Comment: You have to add `, __useDefault: true´ too for this to work. I struggled with this too and found this out by looking inside the source code for how SystemJS uses `newModule` itself internally. Adding this option finally solved the problem. I tried this for SystemJS itself, to register it for the `'systemjs'` module name since it's already loaded, and it only worked after I added this option.

Comment: With this approach, I am getting `newModule is not a function` error on browser with SystemJS v3.1.0, has this been deprecated?

Comment: "newModule is not a function" for me as well.  Anyone have the new way to do this?

Comment: It looks like the newer versions of SystemJS removed `newModule`.